TypeError: value.toDate is not a function
I'm doing a CRUD. I want to modify an Order so the form has to show the current date.
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/orders/${id}/`, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token ${Cookies.get('token')}`
    }
});
const orderDetails = response.data;
setFormData({
    supplier: orderDetails.supplier,
    date: orderDetails.date,
    total: orderDetails.total,
    description: orderDetails.description
});

I have the DatePicker from NextUI
<div className="w-full max-w-xl flex flex-row gap-4">
    <DatePicker
        label='Fecha'
        showMonthAndYearPickers
        value={formData.date}
        onChange={(value) => handleDateChange(value)}
    />
</div>

when I choose an Order I get the error: TypeError: value.toDate is not a function
I tried with new Date(formData.date)  and with parseAbsoluteToLocal(orderDetails.date)  but It's doesn't work.
